# discord.py Giveaway command not showing the full giveaway embed after the 3 questions

Tags: discord.py

Can someone please have a look at my code, as the thing doesn't put the giveaway stuff in the channel. And as I'm fairly new to discord.py I can't see anything wrong with it. It shows the questions asked, but then after the 3 questions it doesn't do anything.

````
async def giveaway(ctx):
    await ctx.send(" Let's create a new Giveaway! Answer the questions within 15 seconds")
    questions = ["Which channel should we host this in?", "What duration should we set for this GA? (S|M|H|D)", "What are we giving away?"]
    answers = []
    def check(m):
        return m.author == ctx.author and m.channel == ctx.channel

    for i, question in enumerate(questions):
            embed = Embed(title=f"Question {i+1}", description=question)
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
            try:
                msg = await bot.wait_for('message', timeout=15.0, check=check)
            except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                await ctx.send("You didn't respond in time, cancelling")
                return
            answers.append(msg.content)
  
    try:
            c_id = int(answers[0][2:-1])
    except:
        await ctx.send(f"You didn't mention a channel properly, mention should look like this {ctx.channel.mention} try again?")
    return
  
    channel = bot.get_channel(c_id)

    time = convert(answers[1])
    if time == -1:
            await ctx.send("You didn't answer with a proper time unit, please use(S|M|H|D)")
            return
    elif time == -2:
            await ctx.send("The time must be an integer")
            return

    prize = answers[2]

    await ctx.send(f"The giveaway will be in {channel.mention} and will last for {answers[1]}")

    embed = discord.Embed(title=":tada: Fun and Free Giveaway! :tada:", description=f"**Prize: **{prize}\n"f"**Hosted By: ** {ctx.author.mention}\n")

    embed.add_field(name = "Hosted by:", value = ctx.author.mention)
    embed.set_footer(text = f"Ends {answers[1]} from now")

    my_msg = await channel.send(embed=embed)

    await my_msg.add_reaction("")

    await asyncio.sleep(time)

    new_msg = await channel.fetch_message(my_msg.id)

    users = await new_msg.reactions[0].users().flatten()
    users.pop(users.index(bot.user))

    winner = random.choice(users)

    await channel.send(f"Congratulations to {winner.mention} you have won {prize}!")```
````

Comment: What exactly is it not showing?

Comment: the giveaway embed, for example after the questions it doesn't show what it's supposed to do

Comment: You are returning after the `try except` block, so it won't run anything after that

Comment: so should I remove the try except?

Comment: remove the `return`, it basically ends the function there

Comment: all of the returns in the command?

Comment: fixed it ty man!

Comment: Next time please add as less code as possible, you're supposed to add a [**minimal** reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), adding your whole command isn't really helpful